# Using glob for assets in angular-cli throws error

Tags: angular-cli

I am using angular-cli verstion 1.0.0-beta.30

my angular-cli.json file has assets property as

```
"assets":[
  {"glob": "**/*","input":"./assets/","output":"./assets/"},
  "favicon.ico"
]
```

My assets folder contains
img - folder
font - folder
.gitkeep - file
message.json - file

I am getting error
"No such file or director stat. project/src/[Object Object]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this glob feature was added quite late in the development cycle.  Upgrading to a final version of angular-cli would probably fix this issue.